# Tuition in the Netherlands for a person with a German family reunion visa

Tags: netherlands, residence-cards, financial

I have a question of the tuition fee for bachelor study in netherland, there are two different level of fees. One for EU citizens and one for none.

However it also shows in law that people who has the same right as the EU citizens do not have to pay as high as the none EU citizens.

I have the family reunion permanent visa for Germany, since my husband is German. We got married less than 3 years which means I only have permanent visa called Aufenthaltserlaubnis but not the Niederlassungserlaubnis 
How much should I be charged for Bachelor's studies tuition in the Netherlands?
Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: It helps if you add links to your statements (*there are two different level* and *it also shows in law*) so that it is **exactly** clear what we're talking about.

Comment: it is pretty clear in my question. I am still at the level of Aufenthaltserlaubnis not Niederlassungserlaubis since we got married less than 3 years. If I already have had the Niederlassungserlaubnis then there won't be a question anymore. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Jan Doggen's question is about links and law which you mentioned regarding study fees, and not about your residential status.